# Implementing MVDR beamformer in the STFT domain

Tags: stft, beamforming

I am trying to implement an MVDR beamformer for the first time. I was reading a couple of papers and books with many different notations and I am a bit confused.

In my case, without loss of generality, I have a spherical microphone array. Given that I produce the steering vector $d(f)$ with respect to a given 3D direction $\Omega_i=(\theta_i,\varphi_i)$, (azimuth and elevation). Let $y(f)=[Y_1(f), Y_2(f),\ldots,Y_M(f)]^T$ be the frequency representation of a single STFT frame. If I understood correctly my MVDR filter should be:

$$h_\text{MVDR}(f)=\frac{\Phi_y^{-1}d(f)}{\bar{d}(f)\Phi_y^{-1}d(f)}$$
Where, $\bar{(\cdot)}$ is the complex conjugate.

Now, my enhanced signal may be computed as:
$$Z(f)=h_\text{MVDR}^H(f)y(f)$$

I do this for each time frame, concatenate the result and follow to inverse STFT.

- Is this a correct implementation?
- If not, where was I wrong?
- How do I estimate $\Phi_y^{-1}$ from my signal? Is that simply `autocorr(y)` in MATLAB?
- Is there a nice python package with references or even one with an implementation for such a filter?

Answer (score 3):

In this context $\Phi_y$ often describes the (estimated) power spectral density matrix  of $y(f)$, which is
$$\Phi_y(f) = E\{y(f) y^H(f)\} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 y_1 \cdot y_1^*(f),& y_1 \cdot y_2^*(f),& \dots    \\
 \vdots        & \ddots    &          \\
 y_M \cdot y_1^*(f),&               & y_M \cdot y_M^*(f)  \\
   \end{bmatrix},$$
where $M$ is the number of channels, and each element of the matrix corresponds to the cross-power spectral density of two channels for this frequency. Consistent estimates of PSDs in blockwise STFT processing can be obtained, for example, using [Welch's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method) (`pwelch` in MATLAB).

I am also unsure about your steering vectors and complex conjugate transposes (which I assume is the $\cdot^H$ in your notation). They need to make the steering vector compensate the delay for a specific direction.

From my memory, I think the formulas should be

$$ h_\text{MVDR}(f) = \frac{\Phi_y^{-1}(f)d(f)}{d^H(f)\Phi_y^{-1}d(f)}$$

and

$$ Z(f) = h_\text{MVDR}(f)^T y(f).$$

I think the orginal MVDR paper is [this one by Capon](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1449208). You might want to double-check notations since a complex conjugate does change the beamformer's output quite a bit.

Edit: Thanks to Stanley Pawlukiewicz for pointing out my error!

Comment: May the downvoter care to explain the downvote, or offer another solution?

Comment: It’s basically incorrect. MVDR uses a cross spectrum matrix. It’s the spatial cross correlation at a single frequency.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right! I'll change my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: What do you need to be clarified regarding the steering vector $d(f)$? It is, as you stated, compensating with respect to a specific vector and I have edited the hermitian operation. does it make it clearer?

Comment: I think so, but doesn't the conjugate in the second formula turn the compensation into an additional delay? Maybe it should be $h_\text{MVDR}(f)^Ty(f)$ instead, I'm not sure right now.

Comment: I am confused about the sizes here.  Your proposition for $\Phi_y(f)$ is of size $M\times M$ while for $M$ channels and $F$ frequency bins $d(f)\in \mathbb{R}^{F\times M}$. Even if I play with transpose to fix this issue, I will get $M\times F$ on the nominator and $F\times F$ on the denominator. I am confused here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, in python, I have used `np.matmul(y,y.conj.T)`. This may correspond with the right-hand side of your $\Phi_y(f)$, but how do I implement the expected value of this? Do I simply use `np.cov(y)` where $y=y(f)=[Y_1(f), Y_2(f),\ldots,Y_M(f)]^T\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times F}$?

Comment: The expected value would be the ideal case, a more practical version of this would be to estimate these matrices over multiple frames and average them (roughly welch's method) or to use recursive PSD estimation. For a simple implementation tough, it might work well enough if you simply multiply the vectors.

Comment: For the sizes, i think $d(f)$ should be $M \times 1$ for each individual frequency. That way, you end up with an $M\times 1$ divided by $1\times 1$ result.